# Below code is weird

Tags: python, closures

```
    >>> def counter(start_at=0):
...     count = [start_at]
...     def incr():
...             count[0] += 1
...             return count[0]
...     return incr
...
>>> count = counter(7)
>>> print count()
8
>>> print count()
9
```

The above code is running fine. I understand. But I thought below code should be same as above.

```
    >>> counter(7)()
8
>>> counter(7)()
8
```

Well, it is not acting like the print count(). Why?

Comment: -1 for the title, please read http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that every `counter(7)` call creates a separate `count` instance and separate `incr` function. When you call them, you actually refer to different variables `count` thus the results are as shown above.

Comment: Thanks. You made it very clear. But I have another question. When the code count=counter(7) run. I think the counter() function should be already finished. So the access to count[0] should be illegal, right? Then why count can continue to access the count[0]? Thanks in advance

Comment: @MingweiLi, it's because variables in Python are actually references to objects, and objects are removed when no reference points to them at all. `counter()` returns a function that inside references the inner variables created by the `counter()` call. As long as the function returned lives, the inner objects will live and be available.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to same behaviour of counter and count then follow below code:

```
>>> count = counter
>>> print count(7)
8
>>> print count(7)
8
```